# UITapGestureRecognizer no label in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have one little problem.

I implement UIableView like

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell;

    UILabel *label = nil;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

        UILongPressGestureRecognizer * longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [label setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        [label setMinimumFontSize:self.FONT_SIZE];
        [label setNumberOfLines:0];
        [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:self.FONT_SIZE]];
        [label setTag:1];
        [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [label setTextColor:[colors getMainTextColor]];

        UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changeCellHeight:)];
        [label addGestureRecognizer:tap];

        [[cell contentView] addSubview:label];
```

This set UITapGestureRecognizer to the Label and it work but it always tap on the first cell.

Method changeCellHeight always show me that indexPath.row  = 1 and I dont know why.

```
-(void)changeCellHeight:(id)sender{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[sender view];
    NSIndexPath *IndexPath = [self.table indexPathForCell:cell];
    DataObject * obj_ = [self.allData objectAtIndex:IndexPath.row];
    if (obj_.canChangeHeight) {
        obj_.needChangeHeight = !obj_.needChangeHeight;
        [self.table reloadData];
    }
}
```

I intentionally put addGestureRecognizer:tap inside if(cell == nil) because I dont want abandoned memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But `[sender view]` isn't a table view cell. It's a label. You're lucky (or unlucky depending on how you look at it) you don't get a crash.

You need to navigate from the label to the cell (superview of superview) and use that instead.

Comment: superviews of superviews is dangerous and fragile.  isDescendentOfView or something might be better.  View hierarchies can change.

Comment: @chadbag, navigating the hierarchy shouldn't be used at all. A relationship should be setup explicitly with the cell so that it can send messages back to a delegate or something like that...